# Is there a shorter notation to make a widget conditionally expanded?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I want to make a widget conditionally expanded I have to write

```
Flexible(
  flex: 2,
  child: Flex(
    direction: isPortrait ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: [
      isPortrait ? _buildFreeTrialButton(context) : Expanded(child: _buildFreeTrialButton(context)),
      isPortrait ? _buildUpgradeButton(context) : Expanded(child: _buildUpgradeButton(context)),
    ],
  ),
)
```

I was wondering is there a way to have a shorter notation then

```
 isPortrait ? _buildFreeTrialButton(context) : Expanded(child: _buildFreeTrialButton(context)),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `Expanded` widget is nothing more than a `Flexible` widget with the parameter `fit` set to `FlexFit.tight`.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/5e97eed89540cc0e027af59847af64e9b6b15447/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart#L4680)

So a more compact way to do what you want would be to do the condition on the flex parameter. Here is a small implementation:

```
Flexible(
  fit: isPortrait ? null : FlexFit.tight,
  child: Container(
    height: height,
    child: _buildFreeTrialButton(context),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As all of it is code, you can always create your own shorter notation by using all the means available when coding, for example methods:

```
Widget _expandedIfPortrait(bool isPortrait, Widget child) {
   return isPortrait ? child : Expanded(child: child);
}
```

or even

```
Widget _expandedIfPortrait(bool isPortrait, WidgetBuilder builder) {
   return isPortrait ? builder(context) : Expanded(child: builder(context));
}
```

So you can call it like

```
children: [
  _expandedIfPortrait(isPortrait, _buildFreeTrialButton(context)),
  _expandedIfPortrait(isPortrait, _buildUpgradeButton(context)),
],
```

or even

```
children: [
  _expandedIfPortrait(isPortrait, _buildFreeTrialButton),
  _expandedIfPortrait(isPortrait, _buildUpgradeButton),
],
```